# Discord API 401 Unauthorized Error when trying to get guild roles

Tags: python, python-requests, discord, flask-dance

So what I'm trying to do is I'm creating some kind of dashboard for my bot and I want to get the current guilds roles. When I try to do that, I get `{'message': '401: Unauthorized', 'code': 0}` as response. I tried everything and looked at multiple questions as well as issues on github

```py
json.loads(discord_oauth.discord.get(f"/api/guilds/{server}/roles", headers={"Authorization": "client-secret-here"}).content)
```

If you ask why I didnt put `Bearer` in front of my client secret thats because the library I'm using already puts that in front. So the header will return like this: `{"Authorization": "Bearer client-secret-here"` (I tried putting that too but it didn't work either)

I tried doing it with requests.get() too but it didnt work either. I always got `{'message': '401: Unauthorized', 'code': 0}` as response. How can I fix this?

(This code doesn't work only when I'm trying to get guild channels and guild roles. It works with guild and user info)

My scopes are: ["guilds", "identify"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP 401 responses are always authorization errors, telling you that you're either not providing the correct credentials, or your credentials are expired.

Did you get a client token from Discord? If so, are you using the syntax provided by the [Discord REST API documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#authentication-example-bot-token-authorization-header) for bots? Based on what I'm seeing, your line should look something like:

```py
token = 'MTk4NjIyNDgzNDcxOTI1MjQ4.Cl2FMQ.ZnCjm1XVW7vRze4b7Cq4se7kKWs'
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {token}"}
result = discord_oauth.discord.get(f"/api/guilds/{server}/roles", headers=headers).content
data = json.loads(result)
```

If you've followed these directions and you're still getting 401 errors, I would bet that your credentials are invalid, implying the token has been revoked. That would mean you should probably get a new token.

Comment: Where can i get a client token? I think thats my problem because i cant seem to find it @ZackWolf

Comment: @Mr.Beanos.- You need to register an application with Discord. The instructions for doing so are in the documentation I linked to, but here's a link to the Apps page: https://discord.com/developers/applications

Comment: I am not using a bot so I used "Bearer Token" in this one, https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#authentication, it still doesnt work @ZachWolf

Comment: Facing the same issue. I even got 401 for my own guild/server by the access token with scopes of guilds and guilds.member.read.